# Foundation Abide - Triggers invalid error on valid inputs if a prior input is invalid

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

For instance, if you have 5 input fields on a form... Input field 3 has valid text and input field 1 is invalid, if you click submit, the input in field 3 will show an error even though it's valid. This only triggers on submit of the form and works fine on live ajax validation.

I've tried using unique class and ids for the div wrappers, unique id for the form, etc... all perfectly done according to the docs.

Has anyone else experienced this and know how to fix it?

Foundation 5.3.3

Answer (score 1):

Found the fix for this:
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/5595

Replace current foundation.abide.js file with the RAW version from the #5606 commit.